Apply fluentd configuration depending on environment variable
Given the following example configuration for fluentd, how could I enable or disable the configuration for Elasticsearch based on an environment variable ENABLE_ELASTICSEARCH?
fluentd will be started in a Docker container, so maybe a custom script could help? Or are there any mechanisms built into fluentd which I could use? The documentation mentions "Embedding Ruby Code" but this seems to work only for configuration values?
<match mytag>
    @type copy
    copy_mode deep
    <store>
        @type relabel
        @label @OPENSEARCH 
    </store>
    <store>
        @type relabel
        @label @ELASTICSEARCH 
    </store>
</match>

<label @OPENSEARCH>
   @include outputs/fluent-opensearch.conf 
</label>

<label @ELASTICSEARCH>
   @include outputs/fluent-elasticsearch.conf 
</label>


Below is how I would address it but there can be more better and efficient ways. Let me know your thoughts!!.
Create another fluent-null.conf which will discard events with @type null match.
<match>
  @type null
</match>

In your fluent.conf, you can update @LABEL sections to use environment variables for @include file names.
<label @OPENSEARCH>
   @include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_OPENSEARCH']}"
</label>

<label @ELASTICSEARCH>
   @include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_ELASTICSEARCH']}"
</label>

Now, you can either point environment variables to actual conf file or null one.
docker run --rm -e FLUENTD_ELASTICSEARCH="fluent-elasticsearch.conf" -e FLUENTD_OPENSEARCH="fluent-opensearch.conf" localfluentd
OR with below command ELASTICSEARCH will be discarded.
docker run --rm -e FLUENTD_ELASTICSEARCH="fluent-null.conf" -e FLUENTD_OPENSEARCH="fluent-opensearch.conf" localfluentd
More explanation in below blog which gives sample repo to test this approach.
https://ranbook.cloud/answers/fluentd-conditional-matches/
